# How to find all invalid views in mysql?

Tags: mysql

So, we managed to do interesting things to our database that created invalid views. We just want to drop these views from the database and move on. 
What I could not find is an easy way to find all invalid views in the database so that I can work from there. Is there an easy way to do this?

Recipe to create an invalid view

```
create table some_table (some_column varchar(20));
insert into some_table(some_column) values('some_data');
create view some_view as (select some_column from some_table);
select * from some_view;

# Now drop the table and test the view
drop table some_table;
select * from some_view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an answer that was somehow deleted.

```
SELECT CONCAT('CHECK TABLE ', table_name, ';') AS my_view_check_statements
FROM information_schema.views 
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/chkstmts.sql';

source '/tmp/chkstmts.sql';
```

Comment: Some interesting scripts present in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html

Answer (score 6):

The solution from Ralph works fine. If you want a query without subselect, try this:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'view'
  AND table_rows is null
  AND table_comment like '%invalid%'
```

The condition *table_rows is null* is important as it will force an evaluation of the view and the error message in the *table_comment* column.

If afterwards you want to fix your view, you can see the original definition with

```
SELECT view_definition
FROM information_schema.views
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database'
  AND table_name = 'your_view'
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way of finding broken views within your MySQL database:

```
SELECT vws.table_schema,vws.table_name 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM  information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_type='VIEW' 
        AND table_comment LIKE '%invalid%'
  ) vws;
```

[Original source of query](http://frodo.looijaard.name/article/mysql-identify-invalid-views)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME 
 FROM information_schema.VIEWS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT IN (
      SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.TABLES
 )
```

Comment: Contr-example: `create table some_table (some_column varchar(20)); create view some_view as (select some_column from some_table); alter table some_table  change column some_column some_column2 varchar(20);`

In this case your check will be failed ;)

Comment: And your check is useless: TABLE_NAME in VIEWS exists in TABLES if it is broken. In this case TABLE_NAME is view name

Comment: If the view is invalid because it points to a table that doesn't exist, then the views name wont be in the tables table, so returned results are views invalid for that reason.

Comment: Really? My tests say that you are wrong. I ran TS query, your query returns empty list but view is broken. I use MySQL 5.6.12-log